# XMLHttpRequest authentication

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am interested in how you would determine using XMLHttpRequest if the user had already authenticated with a server? I can send my request and return data but if I refresh the page and request the data again my logon form is firing even though the session time out has not expired.

Any thoughts?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: So you're using cookie-based authentication? Does refreshing the page delete them?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple options here.  Often times a serve will respond with a login form to any unauthenticated request.  Thus, if you're making an AJAX request that fetches JSON, you can just look at the content-type of the response, ala `xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type')`.  Authenticated responses should be something like `application/json`, while unauthenticated responses will be `text/html` (or something like that.)

But... you can also look at `document.cookie` to see if the user has a session cookie defined.  While this isn't a bullet-proof check (the cookie may be invalid, or the server may have additional checks in place that could still fail the request), it's not an unreasonable check to do.